# How to find determinant of a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

The task at hand is to find the determinant of `A` matrix and find the error in `detResult` variable.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)])
detResult = A[1,1]*A[2,2]-A[1,2]*A[1,2]  #does not compile
```

There are 2 ways in which I could get the answer, but I don't see any small/negligible typo in the given version of `detResult`.

1st way:

```
det1 = A[0,0:1] * A[1,1:2] - A[0,1:] * A[1,0:1]
```

2nd way:

```
det2 = A[0][0] * A[1][1] - A[0][1] * A[1][0]
```

Comment: Indices start with `0` in numpy and python. Does `A[0,0] * A[1,1] - A[0,1] * A[1,0]` answer your question? You can compute determinants with [`np.linalg.det`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html)

Comment: It should be `detResult = A[0,0]*A[1,1]-A[0,1]*A[1,0]`. In Python, indexing starts from 0 not 1. You used 2 as index but it is out of boundary for a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: You're right guys, I came up with 2 versions on my own, but I didn't spot the index was wrong in the given version. Thanks, I'll got to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the inbuilt function in Numpy, `numpy.linalg.det()`. More information can be found on the Numpy Docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html